# Extract DIV ID names found in a specific containing DIV using Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping

I've been using lxml to extract data from a page by xpath. So far, so good. But I have a new challenge:

I have to extract all the IDs of divs in a containing DIV and pass those ID names into a list. I am guessing I can use Beautiful Soup to do this (or possibly also lxml) I'm just not sure how to go about it:

Example, in this I would have to extract "beacon" and "lentil":

```
    <div id="live-events">

       <div class ="events" id="beacon"> 
           ....other things...
       </div>

       <div class="events" id ="lentil">
          ....other things...
       </div>

    </div>
```

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very straightforward:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""
...     <div id="live-events">
... 
...        <div class ="events" id="beacon"> 
...            ....other things...
...        </div>
... 
...        <div class="events" id ="lentil">
...           ....other things...
...        </div>
... 
...     </div>
... """)
>>> live_events = soup.find(id="live-events")
>>> ids = [div["id"] for div in live_events.find_all("div")]
>>> ids
[u'beacon', u'lentil']
```

Comment: Sorry, one last thing. How would I use this with requests rather than a variable with the raw HTML? I'm currently following this as a guideline: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Comment: Surely it's obvious? The page you link to shows how to get the content a document using `requests`, and the code above shows how to turn that content into a BS object. I can't see what you could be having trouble with ...

Comment: Oh, belay that, figured it out. Thanks again.